# Python Dataframe show rows where element from list is present in list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am trying to see if list of lists contains an element from the list.
If the Column D list contains an element from List1, keep the row

```
List 1 = [ 5, 10, 15, 20]
Col A    Col B  Col C   Col D
 A        Ab     Zx      [1 , 2 , 5]
 F        R      T       [6 , 7]
 D        b      d       [10, 12]
```

Expected Output:

```
Col A    Col B  Col C   Col D
     A        Ab     Zx      [1 , 2 , 5]
     D        b      d       [10, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df[pd.DataFrame(df['Col D'].tolist()).isin(List_1).any(1)]
```

Or list comp:

```
df[[any(e in List_1 for e in i) for i in df['Col D']]]
```

---

```
  Col A Col B Col C      Col D
0     A    Ab    Zx  [1, 2, 5]
2     D     b     d   [10, 12]
```

Just incase they are not lists and string representation of lists , try:

```
df[df['Col D'].str.contains('|'.join(map(str,List_1)))]
```

Comment: @Ajinkya did you change the variable `List_1` to original variable name for the list? if yes I cannot reproduce the issue, this solution works for me